# Delphi android cannot use TPath

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I need to store a picture taken from the camera and I am trying to use the code you can find below.

```
ImagePhoto.Bitmap.SaveToFile(  TPath.Combine(TPath.GetCameraPath, getNewName) );
```

In particular the variables names stands for:

- ImagePhoto: a TImage containing the taken picture
- getNewName: a function that returns a string like filename.bmp

I have included `System.IOUtils` in the uses clauses but the TPath doesn't work properly. When I press Ctrl and I click on TPath the IDE opens this

```
TPath = class(TCustomPath)
```

and that's inside the FMX.Objects, not it System.IOUtils! How can I fix this? I am using Delphi Tokyo.

Basically I need to know how to specify that I need the TPath from IOUtils.

Comment: In C++ there are namespaces and they can easily solve this problem. Does Delphi have something like this? btw I don't know why they put the same name of 2 different units...

Comment: You need to have the System.IOUtils declared after (!) the FMX.Objects unit.

Comment: The question should have contained the compiler error. Those details matter. Did you read the error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that *FMX.Objects* appears after *System.IOUtils* in the uses clause. Either change that or qualify the call to *TPath*:

```
ImagePhoto.Bitmap.SaveToFile(System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetCameraPath, getNewName));
```

Comment: So basically the order of the declared units is important in Delphi?

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi Yes, but you can also take advantage of namespaces and unit scope names. Read more about these [**here**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_Namespaces_with_Delphi)

Comment: Unfortunately, yes! Although, in a perfect world it shouldn't happen. Both of the class names are quite logical and sensible - nevertheless they clash. `TMonitor` is another example. This also happens in real world languages.

Comment: *"So basically the order of the declared units is important in Delphi?"* 
Yes. The rule is: the last listed unit is the first where the identifier will be searched.